# What is the location of named semaphores in Windows OS

Tags: c, windows, semaphore

In Linux OS, named semaphores are created at /dev/shm/ location using sem_open API. I am creating named semaphore in Windows using CreateSemaphore. In which location are the named semaphores created in Windows?

Answer (score 4):

Windows *named* semaphores exist within the kernel's internal object namespace. This database has a filesystem-like hierarchical tree structure, but is not visible through regular filesystem functions. Use the [Object Viewer tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/winobj) from Sysinternals (now a subsidiary of Microsoft) to explore that space. Semaphores, unsurprisingly, have the object type *Semaphore*. Of other objects, the mutex is called *Mutant* (apparently, after David Cutler's reference to these as “mutant semaphores”, private communication). The *EventPair* object is not available though the Win32 API. All other synchronization primitives are self-recognizable there.

I do not think that the API used to access this data space from user space is fully documented. Windows DDK headers is are interesting read indeed.

Unnamed objects (those that are created with the `NULL` passed as object name) are for single process use, and only optionally inherited by its child processes. These are not registered in the kernel object namespace.

Unlike POSIX semaphores, all Windows objects are automatically removed when the last handle to these is closed (as if `sem_open` always called `sem_unlink`), and all process  handles are closed by the kernel's executive when the process terminates, be it a normal termination or an abort. I am mentioning that in case the motivation for your question was to verify that there are no semaphores left behind when all processes that use them die.

Comment: In Windows, closing the handle to a semaphore doesn't increase the semaphore count, so you have to make sure you call ReleaseSemaphore before your process terminates, otherwise other processes relying on the same semaphore can be starved.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sync/semaphore-objects

Answer (score 2):

There is no filesystem or other location for semaphores in Windows, you only access them via [`CreateSemaphore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Linux has virtual filesystems that provide access to several named kernel objects, but in Windows this is not the case and there rarely is any need for that.

More about [kernel namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382954%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Windows has a kernel object namespace which is somewhat similar to a filesystem. See the function's documentation.

Comment: @cremno Yes, but it's not really presented to the outside world. One might create a way to show it, though, like Powershell's IIS/SQL Server things.