# Semaphore (IPC) in R

Tags: r, ipc, semaphore

Is there any way to use semaphores (IPC) in R? I have several R scripts running in paralel and I want only certain (smaller) number of them to enter the critical stage of the script. E.g. in C on Linux, this would be easily accomplished by [named semaphores](https://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview) shared between processes, but how to do this in R?

1. Solution should work on MS Windows as well. For example, `bettermc::sem_open()` is not supported on Windows. [It looks like Windows support semaphores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-semaphore-objects), so it should be possible. It also looks like [named semaphores should also work on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31852055/684229) for the case of communication between different processes.
2. Solution should not only work for 'parallel' processing within one R session, but also for totally separate R sessions (separate independent processes).
3. I found https://github.com/gbenison/R-semaphore but I didn't test this, it doesn't seem to be on CRAN; I prefer solution which is available within CRAN packages already.

Comment: What type of cluster are you running? Did you use the parallel package or something else? Do they share memory or not?

Comment: @JanvanderLaan no cluster, just separate R sessions.

Comment: Specifically what OSes are you hoping to run this on?

Comment: @SargeATM Windows, as I wrote, Unix already has a solutions, that's enough for me.

Answer (score 3):

### Use boost.mutex from synchronicity (if you want only 1 process in the critical section at a time)

In any process that has a critical section, do the following.

```
m = boost.mutex('global_name_of_my_mutex')
lock(m)
# Critical section of code
unlock(m)
```

The R package synchronicity is available by running:

```
install.packages('synchronicity')
```

It provides `boost.mutex` which is an R wrapper around C++ boost's `named_upgradable_mutex`.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/synchronicity/versions/1.3.5

Comment: Thanks. That's closest to an answer (though I wanted for more processes to be able to enter the critical section, like in semaphores). But I just randomly played with it and ended up deadlocking one process with itself (not sure why), sometimes it behaved strange.

Answer (score 1):

### Wrap win32 semaphores using Rcpp

*r_semaphores.cpp*

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>


// [[Rcpp::export]]
uintptr_t create_semaphore( Rcpp::String name, LONG initial_count, LONG maximum_count)
{

    // Create a named semaphore with initial and max counts
    HANDLE hSemaphore = CreateSemaphore( 
        NULL,                   // default security attributes
        initial_count,  
        maximum_count,                
        name.get_cstring());    // named semaphore

    return (uintptr_t)hSemaphore;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool release_semaphore( uintptr_t hSemaphore, LONG release_count)
{
    return ReleaseSemaphore((HANDLE)hSemaphore, release_count, NULL);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
DWORD wait_for_single_object(uintptr_t hHandle)
{
    return WaitForSingleObject((HANDLE)hHandle, INFINITE);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool close_handle(uintptr_t hHandle)
{
    return CloseHandle((HANDLE)hHandle);
}
```

In R:

```
> library('Rcpp')
> sourceCpp('r_semaphores.cpp')

# create named semaphore that can be accessed by any process on the machine
> create_semaphore('sargeATM_works_out', 12, 12)
[1] 876
> wait_for_single_object(876)
[1] 0
...critical section here...
> release_semaphore(876,1)
[1] TRUE
> close_handle(876)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I know this is a partial solution. But between this and using POSIX bettermc on 'nix, a thin wrapper can be created with a simple API that chooses the win32 or POSIX semaphores based on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

You could have look at the `lockfile` package. This packages uses OS-routines to safely create lock files. This is probably the easiest solution.

Looking at the documentation of the C-routines you linked to. It would not be too difficult to wrap those into some C/C++-functions called from R. It would probably be only a couple of lines of code using `Rcpp` and/or the `inline` package.

But I am also wondering if you really need this. If you have some code doing some calculation in parallel followed by some calculations if those are finished, there are other solutions. One is to start your processes from R using the `parallel` package. You can the use the functionality of that package to control the synchronisation from your main R-process. Another solution is to first run the first computations and then, when those are finished, start new R-sessions for the second part. The overhead of starting R-sessions is generally quite small (couple of seconds). You can use a tool such as `make` or `snakemake` to coordinate this.

Comment: Thanks Jan! 1) But isn't file locking for just one process to have the lock? I need more general solution - to have max `k` > 0 processes to share the resource... i.e. what semaphores do. 2) *"But I am also wondering if you really need this." let this to me please :-) It's the easiest way out :-)